# Binary Compression RLE

Tags: compression, run-length-encoding

I used RLE algorithm for my binary data compression project but it gives me
 ratio 16% how can i improved this ratio by improving RLE algorithm ?
if anyone can recommend better algorithms for binary data compression please help!

Comment: In which programming language? Also, show us what you actually already got. Give us some code.